# Помогите доработать алгоритм модуля (PHP + JS)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, алгоритм

Доброго времени суток. Впервые пишу модуль для своего сайта на php и js, помогите разобраться в связывании его запчастей воедино. Суть модуля - парсить картинки и ссылки на видео с других сайтов автоматически по названию добавляемой на сайт новости (CMS DLE), дополняя её тем самым случайным тематическим медиа контентом.

Основной функционал готов - php скрипт вытаскивает, оформляет тегами и возвращает нужную информацию в виде "картинка1.jpg - описание, картинка2.jpg - описание..." и тд. Возникли проблемы, когда дошел до связывания функциональной части и пользовательской.

В CMS DLE при добавлении статей используются т.н. дополнительные поля - заранее расставленные в шаблоне и оформленные инпуты текста. Так вот, хотелось бы, чтобы эти картинки и видео были вставлены в разные поля. Пробовал отправлять несколько $.post запросов по нажатию кнопки в php скрипт, используя идентификаторы типа pic1, pic2 и тд. Php скрипт выполняет проверку типа if ($_POST['pic1']) и возвращает первую картинку, а JS вставляет её в доп поле с указанным идентификатором. В итоге получается десяток $.post запросов и понимание, что это явно не комильфо, хоть и работает как надо.

Прошу подсказать методы, алгоритм или еще какую полезную информацию, как это красивее и не столь монолитно выполнить, желательно в формате "для новичка".

Кратко:

1. Есть php-скрипт - принимает url и возвращает информацию;
2. Полученную информацию надо разбить на 10 частей (средствами JS) и вставить в текстовые поля с разными id;
3. Ввиду малого опыта не понимаю, как "красивее" и "правильнее" связать эти 2 части.

Comment: [Ничего не понимаю © Коллега](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vlUe8ciyh4w)

Comment: Разбейте в голове и на листочке весь код так, чтобы не было повторений одного и того же функционала. Далее разделите обработку данных на логические составляющие так, чтобы опять не было повторений. Предположим если есть текстовые данные которые нужно обработать неким кодом и есть видео данные, которые точно так же нужно обработать неким кодом, то нужно создать модуль который будет принимать (a=данные)(b=обработка данных) и пусть этот модуль в своих недрах парсит и выдает только уже пережеванную информацию, которую можно продолжить подготавливать дальше при помощи АДАПТЕРОВ. И ПРОКСИРУЙТЕ все.